# undefined method `each' in controller for create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a undefined method `each' that points to the create method in photos controller. It looks like @photo.user = current_user is the culprit but I don't understand how to fix it. Tried a few different methods but was unsuccessful. Any ideas on how can I fix this?

photo controller:

```
  def new
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    @photo.user = current_user
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created photos."
      redirect_to user_photos_path(current_user)
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    if @photo.update_attributes(paramas[:photo])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated photo."
      redirect_to @photo.gallery
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed photo."
    redirect_to @photo.gallery
  end
end
```

photo model:

```
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :gallery_id, :name, :image, :remote_image_url
  belongs_to :gallery
  has_many :gallery_users, :through => :gallery, :source => :user
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validate :quota

  private

  def quota
    return unless user
    if gallery.photos.count > 4
      errors[:base] << "Maximum photos uploaded, delete to upload more"
    end 
  end
end
```

User model:

```
 has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :role, :age, :age_end, :password_confirmation, :about_me, :feet, :inches, :password, :birthday, :career, :children, :education, :email, :ethnicity, :gender, :height, :name, :password_digest, :politics, :religion, :sexuality, :user_drink, :user_smoke, :username, :zip_code
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_format_of :email, with: /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  has_many :photos
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }
  ROLES = %w[admin user guest banned]

  # models/user.rb
  after_create :setup_gallery

  def received_messages
      Message.received_by(self)
    end

 def unread_messages?
   unread_message_count > 0 ? true : false
 end

 def unread_messages
   received_messages.where('read_at IS NULL')
 end

 def sent_messages
   Message.sent_by(self)
 end

 # Returns the number of unread messages for this user
 def unread_message_count
   eval 'messages.count(:conditions => ["recipient_id = ? AND read_at IS NULL", self.user_id])'
 end

  def to_s; username
  end

  def has_role?(role_name)
    role.present? && role.to_sym == role_name.to_sym
  end

  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end

  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end


  private
  def setup_gallery
     self.galleries << Gallery.create
   end
end
```

Gallery model:

```
   attr_accessible :title, :body, :name
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :photos

end
```

photo upload view:

```
<%= form_for @photo, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :gallery_id %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </p>
        <%= f.label :remote_image_url, "or image URL" %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :remote_image_url %>
    </p>            
    <p> <%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

gallery controller:

```
 def index
    @galleries = Gallery.all
  end

  def show
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
  end

  def create
    @gallery = Gallery.new(params[:gallery])
    if @gallery.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created gallery."
      redirect_to @gallery
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    if @gallery.update_attributes(params[:gallery])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated gallery."
      redirect_to gallery_url
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    @gallery.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroy gallery."
    redirect_to galleries_url
  end
end
```

Request parameters from error:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Pher65dG6gRU9NGgv2q1ot0cfjq+MELgXE6dOtvcrY0=",
 "photo"=>{"gallery_id"=>"",
 "name"=>"dssdsdds",
 "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f82c171cb18 @original_filename="X-box-720-8.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[image]\"; filename=\"X-box-720-8.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/2_/p3vcr8d93ydbsrcv63k2n56r0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130502-20210-1498gwp>>,
 "remote_image_url"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Create Photo"}
```

Comment: An actual error message and stack trace, as well as a description of the "few different methods" you tried unsuccessfully would make this a much better question. As it is, there's really no way for anyone to help.

Comment: I will add some more files but I wanted someone to look at the create method to see if everything looks good there as it's pointing to it. As with this modified coding it's not able to save/create photo which is causing it to not work. If I revert back to my old code it allows me to upload fine.

Comment: Have you set in your Photo model `belongs_to :user`? Does your Photos table has a column 'user_id' ?

Comment: Please post full error message and relevant view/controller code for us to help.

Comment: @MrYoshiji it does not have a column user_id, only gallery_id.

Comment: @Huy I added view for photo upload and gallery controller. That should be all the needed files for code.

Comment: our question is way to localized and don't fit what is expected in stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have 2 associations for the `Photo` model that are both called `:user`.  You are also missing the `:gallery` association being referenced in has-many-through.  Firstly, add the`:gallery` association before the other associations are declared:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ... # your list of attributes
  belongs_to :gallery
  ...
```

Then change:

```
has_many :user, :through => :gallery
```

to:

```
has_many :gallery_users, :through => :gallery, :source => :user
```

Comment: That gives undefined local variable or method `gallery' when I use your modified has_many (and I kept my belongs_to).

Comment: You must be missing the `belongs_to :gallery` statement that should be written before using it in a has-many-through association - updated.

Comment: No I did that before submitting the comment. Got a undefined method `user=' error so I just reverted back. What you did looks right. It must be in my photo controller for the create action.

Comment: Can you repost your Photo, Gallery, and User models?  I think something is still misconfigured there...

Comment: What happened to the original `belongs_to :user` in your Photo model?  That was supposed to stay...

Comment: I was switching it back and forth, did not know both were needed. Even so it still produces undefined method `photos' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: Yes it does, because you have `gallery_id` set to `nil` in your request.  So your `redirect_to @photo.gallery` is routing to a non-existent gallery that can't load and certainly has no `photos` :)

Comment: So with both belongs_to added (gallery then user) I get this error undefined method `photos' for nil:NilClass. Shows this on page: app/models/photo.rb:14:in `quota'
app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:10:in `create'. I have been messing around with the create method and quota in the model which is why this is a late response. It's a routing error I have to fix I believe. Hopefully good news I can produce soon!

Comment: Your `quota` validation is calling `gallery.photos` - but since `gallery` is `nil` (because you passed a `:gallery_id` of `nil` in your request), it can't find any `photos` for `nil`.  Either ensure that you have a valid `gallery_id` attached, or skip this check if `gallery` is `nil`.

Comment: You have been a big help. Thanks for sticking with me to the end. Will keep all the pointers stored in my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem

```
  has_many :user, :through => :gallery
  belongs_to :user
```

The association logic is wrong.

I'm afraid you must start checking from model level. I can't provide more help with current info.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will try to find a working one.